# boto3 API insufficient funds error when publishing HITs at mturk

Tags: boto3, mturk

I am using boto3 API (1.26.41) to publish HITs at mturk which has my aws account linked in with a valid credit card. However, the API returns an insufficient funds error and calls for pre-paid HITs which is not an option now.
My Mturk account is linked to my aws, and prepaid HITs are not an option now as far as I understand.
Here is the exact error message:
“botocore.errorfactory.RequestError: An error occurred (RequestError) when calling the CreateHIT operation: This Requester has insufficient funds in their account to complete this transaction. Please visit https://requester.mturk.com/prepayments/new to purchase Prepaid HITs.”

I updated boto3 to the latest version assuming that previous versions are not consistent with the recent changes at mturk (i.e., no pre-paid hits) but it is unlikly that this is the issue.

I contacted mturk through their contact forms but no response.

Comment: Running through the same issue. Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @guhuru, I posted the answer. All the best in getting that setup.

Answer (score 1):

MTurk seems to set a limit which is almost $0. I had to contact them via multiple channels (contact forms in AWS and MTurk) to have that raised. They have raised it now to 1k. It takes time and patience and their customer support is unfortunately hopeless.